# SIGBUS(BUS_ADRALN) Unable to Understand

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I am facing strange issue of SIGBUS I tried to debug but unable to do so.

It is happening when I click `UIButton`, even no code there, all other controls of that `viewController` working fine.

**Steps that I followed so far to debug the issue**

1. I thought there may be memory issue but it is not.
2. I commented out the code in that function it is even there.
3. It is not related to view controller retain issue as other actions related to other `UIButton` are working great.
4. I detach the function to that `UIButton`, still on clicking that crash is there.
5. It is happening in release mode not in debug mode.

**Here is the crash log:**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
12.067089    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x1c08f900 complete. fd: 46, err: 0
12.067751    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x1c08f900 event 1. err: 0
12.453127    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac325 TCP Conn 0x1c08f900 started
15.122654    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472be45 TCP Conn 0x17e05970 SSL Handshake DONE
15.644697    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472bd7f TCP Conn 0x17e05970 starting SSL negotiation
15.645127    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17e05970 complete. fd: 44, err: 0
15.646451    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17e05970 event 1. err: 0
34.035038    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17db2ba0 complete. fd: 32, err: 0
34.036185    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17db2ba0 event 1. err: 0
34.365038    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac325 TCP Conn 0x17db2ba0 started
34.684175    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472be45 TCP Conn 0x17e988d0 SSL Handshake DONE
34.893697    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472be45 TCP Conn 0x17e93b20 SSL Handshake DONE
34.994917    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472bd7f TCP Conn 0x17e988d0 starting SSL negotiation
34.995444    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17e988d0 complete. fd: 29, err: 0
34.996935    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17e988d0 event 1. err: 0
35.065026    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17da6510 complete. fd: 27, err: 0
35.066004    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17da6510 event 1. err: 0
35.136351    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac325 TCP Conn 0x17e988d0 started
35.157776    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472be45 TCP Conn 0x17e7ab10 SSL Handshake DONE
35.224726    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472bd7f TCP Conn 0x17e93b20 starting SSL negotiation
35.225286    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17e93b20 complete. fd: 19, err: 0
35.226874    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17e93b20 event 1. err: 0
35.421109    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac325 TCP Conn 0x17da6510 started
35.421548    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac325 TCP Conn 0x17e93b20 started
35.632792    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472be45 TCP Conn 0x17e6beb0 SSL Handshake DONE
35.785237    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472bd7f TCP Conn 0x17e7ab10 starting SSL negotiation
35.785632    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17e7ab10 complete. fd: 12, err: 0
35.785958    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17e7ab10 event 1. err: 0
35.830428    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17d5c550 complete. fd: 25, err: 0
35.832020    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17d5c550 event 1. err: 0
35.995985    CFNetwork                  0x000000002472bd7f TCP Conn 0x17e6beb0 starting SSL negotiation
35.996763    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ab1a5 TCP Conn 0x17e6beb0 complete. fd: 15, err: 0
35.998519    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac2a7 TCP Conn 0x17e6beb0 event 1. err: 0
36.201810    CFNetwork                  0x00000000247ac325 TCP Conn 0x17e6beb0 started`
```

Comment: Please post the full crash report. What you posted does not show the actual stack trace of the crashing thread.

Comment: i got it working, i will post my answer shortly bit busy in work :)